# Socket exception on downloading big file

Tags: java, android, socketexception

My app needs to download large files. After some time I get

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
```

I believe it's because the device is going to sleep or wifi.

So how i should handle this ? I want that user could download a large file no matter how much time it will take.

File downloading is done using:

```
HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uriToFile).openConnection();
con.connect();

FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufferLength = 0;

while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

}

fileOutput.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing any of your code.

Comment: You might want to try increasing `socket.setSoTimeout(nnnn);`

Comment: are you sure you are getting some response from server?

Comment: Yes i am getting response. So what timeout i should set ? 60000?

Comment: @paulsm4 That sets a read timeout. This is a connection timeout.

Comment: @Streetboy - does your HTTP server support the `Range` header for whatever you are downloading or is it streaming the content? In that case you can resume your download by juggling a few HTTP headers.

Comment: Yap support and if i want to have appropriate download method i need resume

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle it, other than by retrying the connection. You can lower the default connection timeout of about 75 seconds, but you can't raise it.

Comment: Why do i need to lower time out ? And how to do this if i am downloading file using HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: @Streetboy As I didn't say you 'need to lower the timeout', I have no answer to offer. Ask someone who thinks its a good idea. I don't.